# PHP: foreach warnings on simplexml

Tags: php, xml

PHP and XML question:

Here is the var_dump i get from parsed xml.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#47 (6) {
    ["link"]=> array(4) {
        ...
    }
    ["entry"]=> array(11) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, when I use:

```
foreach ($parsedReturn->link as $item)
```

or,

```
foreach ($parsedReturn->entry as $item)
```

I get warnings as such:

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: and what does var_dump($parsedReturn->entry) return?

Comment: Unluckily, `var_dump()` is not a reliable way to inspect a `SimpleXMLElement` object. Perhaps you can provide a short example?

Comment: welcome, I'm gonna need more information to go on. Could we please see the xml and what your trying to get to ?

Comment: Can you post parts of your XML file?

Answer (score -1):

The "link" could be attribute, so you would have to use `$parsedReturn['link']`.

Comment: Please read the PHP manual about SimpleXML and the way to access attributes in it. Ever heard of `ArrayAccess`?